# Adding a user to a WildFly server, results in error

Tags: wildfly

I am trying to add a user to WildFly server but get an error:

> ./add-user.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found

I suppose I need to change the `JAVA_HOME` location in a `.conf` file but have done so in the `.conf` files of the `wildfly/bin` directory. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The `add-user.sh` script doesn't source any configuration file, so you have to provide the Java binary through your environment.

You can do this in multiple ways :

- through a `JAVA` variable pointing to the `java` executable :

  ```
  export JAVA=/path/to/jdk_install/bin/java
  ./add-user.sh [...]
  ```
- through a `JAVA_HOME` variable pointing to the Java installation directory :

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk_install/
  ./add-user.sh [...]
  ```
- by including the Java's installation `bin` directory to your `PATH` :

  ```
  export PATH="/path/to/jdk_install/bin:$PATH"
  ./add-user.sh [...]
  ```

Note that these may vary depending on the WildFly or JBoss EAP version ; I gathered these from reading the script of a `wildfly-8.1.0.Final` installation.
If you're not sure this applies to your own version and if you have even the most basic understanding of shell scripts you should check your own : they're only a few dozens lines long and are well commented.

Answer (score 2):

Your java path is wrong. 
You can observe that in below line there is extra '/bin/java'. You should remove that.

> ./add-user.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found

To do so, in your adduser.sh/.bat file  replace

```
    # Setup the JVM
    if [ "x$JAVA" = "x" ]; then
    if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" != "x" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    else
        JAVA="java"
    fi
fi
```

To

```
# Setup the JVM
    if [ "x$JAVA" = "x" ]; then
    if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" != "x" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME"
    else
        JAVA="java"
    fi
fi
```

This does the magic for me.